# How to fix 'Execution default of goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:4.0.2:aggregate failed.: NullPointerException' in Java maven project?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, owasp

I am setting up owasp dependency check plugin in my project in order to get owasp dependency vulnerability report but I am getting the below error:

[image]

I tried upgrading my maven version to the latest, it didn't work. I also tried looking for other sites, blogs but didn't get much help.

I looked in https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/1401 too for a solution but it didn't work for me.

Please find my maven and java version below:
[image]

Comment: Could you execute the same Maven build with option `-X`? `mvn -X <goal>`. It will provide more information about the failure.

Comment: Thanks, @MincongHuang for the reply. The dependency plugin was not installed properly, even though my cntlm was running (my company uses proxy servers). I manually downloaded it and kept in my repository to resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to know that you resolved the problem :)